# Spring CSS for making input fields grow

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I few weeks ago I found a great spring example with spring style sheets but I can't find them now.  This example would use spring lib to make the input fields grow as the user clicked on them.

It looked just like this one but all I had to do was add a tag..

http://tumblr.gesteves.com/post/475773360/css-glow-effects-with-box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Spring CSS but I did it using jQuery.Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/nyG8T/embedded/result/)**.
It will dynamically increase the inputs width to adapt user input.